# storing pointer to member function does not work for clang++

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

when i use clang++ i can only call the pointer-to-member function i can't cast it or assign it to a variable to call i when needed (i want to store this variable to an array of functions) but with g++ i can do that take this for example

```
class Base {
    public:
        typedef void (Base::*A)();
        virtual void some_func() = 0;
};
class B: public Base {
    public:
        void some_func() {
            return
        }
};
int main() {
    B b;
    auto h = (Base::A)&Base::some_func;
    typedef void (*my_function)();
    auto some_func = (my_function)(b.*h);
    some_func();
    return 0;
}
```

with g++ this do compile and run, but with clang++ i get 
`reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?` ( please note that i can't use any std::x functions in my code because the code run on bare metal

Comment: And you spammed the C tag - why?

Comment: You are casting `b.*h` to `my_function` type and you expect this to do what?  Note that the code above clearly doesn't compile and run in g++, you are at the very least missing a `;`.  [MCVE] please.

Comment: You can't cast a non-static member method pointer to a function pointer. A member method pointer requires an instance (`this`) which function pointers to not. The pointer `some_func` would have to somehow bundle `b`.

Comment: Note that (if you correct the error at `return`) gcc produces a warning about your cast to `my_function`. Visual Studio 2015 also rejects the code with a similar error.

Comment: except for the semicolon i missed at line 9, this code compile and run with `g++ (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005`

Comment: Then add the semicolon.  When I add state to `B`, [it segfaults](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9b71e30ca99a746).  So again, I do not know what you *expect* it to do.

Comment: i expect it to call the class B some_func

Comment: @ForKoding And what do you expect `this` to be in it?  Again, please press the <kbd>edit</kbd> button and actually make your code valid in the question.

Comment: to be `b` instance

Comment: @ForKoding Well, that doesn't work on g++ either.  See my link named "segfault" above.  Or [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/960d24f83071f8b0) without a `std::string`.

Comment: but without calling any member variable this compile in g++ but not clang++, is this g++ bug ? and take a look at this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html

Comment: @ForKoding What you are trying to do is not supported in c++. A non-static member function pointer and a function pointer are different mechanisms and are not interchangeable. Consider using `std::function` instead. While gcc allows your example to compile, using that cast pointer is not portable. gcc is kind enough to issue a warning about it.

Comment: Good rundown on why what you're trying can't work and strategies to fix it: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members Remember that a cast tells the compiler to turn off its type-checking brains and trust that you are right. So you better be right because correct or not, the program will compile.

Comment: @user4581301 you can post your comment as an answer so i can select it

Comment: Don't worry about it. It would be a link-only answer, and we frown on those 'round these parts.

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing the [Bound member functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html) extension in g++. You're casting to the wrong kind of function pointer, which has undefined behaviour:

```
typedef void (*my_function)();
auto some_func = (my_function)(b.*h);
some_func();
```

The `(my_function)(b.*h)` expression resolves the virtual dispatch to determine which overriding function would be called by `(b.*h)()`, but to actually invoke that function through the returned pointer you still need to provide a `this` pointer to an object. So `my_function` should take a single argument of type `B*`, and you should provide a pointer to a `B` when you call that function pointer.

To use the extension correctly you should be doing:

```
typedef void (*my_function)(B*);
auto some_func = (my_function)(b.*h);
some_func(&b);
```

This is a non-standard GNU extension and is not supported by Clang. As far as I can see there is no way to get Clang to accept this code.

I've reported a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80311) saying that your misuse of the extension should be an error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in g++, it permits you to cast a pointer to member function with 0 arguments to a function pointer, and calling it will result in invoking that member function with a corrupt/missing `this` pointer.

In addition, the expression `b.*m`, where `m` is a member function and `b` is a class will evaluate virtual dispatch, and the resulting object can be then cast to a function pointer that has evaluated that virtual dispatch.  It will still have a corrupt `this` value.

Both of these are illegal operations under the standard; the program is either ill defined, or using it is undefined behavior.

In g++, the fact that the `this` pointer is garbage is a good reason why this isn't a very useful strategy.  [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/960d24f83071f8b0) is an example of it being built with some state in `B` and it not compiling on clang++ and segfaulting on g++.

A member function and a pointer to object are two things.  Storing them both in one thing (a function pointer) is not going to work, regardless of how you hack it.

There are a number of ways to approach this.  The simplest is to use `std::function`, but you are banned from using the standard library.

The next easiest way is to write your own `std::function` variant.  I've done this -- a "delegate" that supports storing pointers-to-lambdas, pointers to functions, (pointers to objects + pointers to member functions) that are call compatible with a given signature.

All of these are trivial "plain old data", so you can create a simple buffer, copy their value into the buffer, and save a function that knows how to take a pointer-to-the-buffer and invoke it.

```
template<class Sig, unsigned Sz=3*sizeof(void*)>
struct fun;
template<class R, class...Args, unsigned Sz>
struct fun<R(Args...), Sz> {
  using invoker_t = R(*)(void*, Args&&...);
  invoker_t invoker;
  unsigned char buffer[Sz];
  template<class D>
  struct invoker_base_t {
    using invoker_sig = R(*)(void* self, Args&&...args);
    static invoker_sig invoker() {
      return [](void* self, Args&&...args)->R {
        return (*static_cast<D*>(self))(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
      };
    }
  };
  template<class T, class M>
  struct mem_fun_invoker_t:invoker_base_t<mem_fun_invoker_t<T,M>> {
    T* t;
    M m;
    mem_fun_invoker_t(T* tin, M min):t(tin), m(min) {}
    mem_fun_invoker_t(mem_fun_invoker_t const&)=default;
    R operator()(Args&&...args) {
      return (t->*m)(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
    }
  };
  template<class T, class M>
  static mem_fun_invoker_t<T, M> mem_fun_invoker(T* t, M m){ return {t, m}; }
  template<class T>
  struct ptr_invoker_t:invoker_base_t<ptr_invoker_t<T>> {
    T* t;
    ptr_invoker_t(T* tin):t(tin) {}
    ptr_invoker_t(ptr_invoker_t const&)=default;
    R operator()(Args&&...args) {
      return (*t)(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
    }
  };
  template<class T>
  static ptr_invoker_t<T> ptr_invoker(T* t){ return {t}; }
  template<class T, class U, class Ret, class...Ts>
  fun(T* t, Ret(U::*mem)(Ts...)) {
    auto invoke = mem_fun_invoker( t, mem );
    static_assert(sizeof(invoke) <= Sz);
    ::new( (void*)buffer ) decltype(invoke)(invoke);
    invoker = invoke.invoker();
  }
  template<class T, class U, class Ret, class...Ts>
  fun(T const* t, Ret(U::*mem)(Ts...)const) {
    auto invoke = mem_fun_invoker( t, mem );
    static_assert(sizeof(invoke) <= Sz);
    ::new( (void*)buffer ) decltype(invoke)(invoke);
    invoker = invoke.invoker();
  }

  template<class Ret, class...Ts>
  fun(Ret(*f)(Ts...)) {
    auto invoke = ptr_invoker( f );
    static_assert(sizeof(invoke) <= Sz);
    ::new( (void*)buffer ) decltype(invoke)(invoke);
    invoker = invoke.invoker();
  }
  // TODO: SFINAE
  template<class Lambda>
  fun(Lambda&& lambda) {
    auto invoke = ptr_invoker( &lambda );
    static_assert(sizeof(invoke) <= Sz);
    ::new( (void*)buffer ) decltype(invoke)(invoke);
    invoker = invoke.invoker();
  }
  R operator()(Args...args) {
    return invoker(&buffer, static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
  }
  explicit operator bool()const {return invoker;}
};
```

the above needs a quality sweep and more asserts and some SFINAE.

[But it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99352e83ae285940).

`fun<Sig>` is a bare bones variant of `std::function` that has almost no state.  The missing SFINAE needs to test if `Lambda` is signature compatible **and** not equal to `fun` type itself.

These objects are roughly 4 pointers in size; you can configure how big with the `Sz` argument.  2 may be enough to fit member functions and a `this` pointer.  I rounded up to 3.

These things can also store pointers to functions.

They can store pointers to lambdas, or variations of `fun`, but do not extend the lifetime of said lambda.  This is dangerous, but often useful.

Like `std::function` they do not require signatures to match exactly.  Unlike C++14's `std::function`, if `R` is `void`, the stored objects must also return `void`.  Fixing this is more work:

```
namespace details {
  template<class Sig, class D>
  struct invoker_base_t;
  template<class R, class...Args, class D>
  struct invoker_base_t<R(Args...), D> {
    using invoker_sig = R(*)(void* self, Args&&...args);
    static invoker_sig invoker() {
      return [](void* self, Args&&...args)->R {
        return (*static_cast<D*>(self))(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
      };
    }
  };
  template<class...Args, class D>
  struct invoker_base_t<void(Args...), D> {
    using invoker_sig = void(*)(void* self, Args&&...args);
    static invoker_sig invoker() {
      return [](void* self, Args&&...args)->void {
        (*static_cast<D*>(self))(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
      };
    }
  };
  template<class Sig, class T, class M>
  struct mem_fun_invoker_t;
  template<class R, class...Args, class T, class M>
  struct mem_fun_invoker_t<R(Args...), T, M>:
    invoker_base_t<R(Args...), mem_fun_invoker_t<R(Args...),T,M> >
  {
    T* t;
    M m;
    mem_fun_invoker_t(T* tin, M min):t(tin), m(min) {}
    mem_fun_invoker_t(mem_fun_invoker_t const&)=default;
    R operator()(Args&&...args) {
      return (t->*m)(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
    }
  };
  template<class...Args, class T, class M>
  struct mem_fun_invoker_t<void(Args...), T, M>:
    invoker_base_t<void(Args...), mem_fun_invoker_t<void(Args...),T,M> >
  {
    T* t;
    M m;
    mem_fun_invoker_t(T* tin, M min):t(tin), m(min) {}
    mem_fun_invoker_t(mem_fun_invoker_t const&)=default;
    void operator()(Args&&...args) {
      (t->*m)(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
    }
  };
  template<class Sig, class T>
  struct ptr_invoker_t;
  template<class R, class...Args, class T>
  struct ptr_invoker_t<R(Args...), T>:
    invoker_base_t<R(Args...), ptr_invoker_t<R(Args...),T> >
  {
    T* t;
    ptr_invoker_t(T* tin):t(tin) {}
    ptr_invoker_t(ptr_invoker_t const&)=default;
    R operator()(Args&&...args) {
      return (*t)(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
    }
  };
  template<class...Args, class T>
  struct ptr_invoker_t<void(Args...), T>:
    invoker_base_t<void(Args...), ptr_invoker_t<void(Args...),T> >
  {
    T* t;
    ptr_invoker_t(T* tin):t(tin) {}
    ptr_invoker_t(ptr_invoker_t const&)=default;
    void operator()(Args&&...args) {
      (*t)(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
    }
  };
}
template<class Sig, unsigned Sz=3*sizeof(void*)>
struct fun;
template<class R, class...Args, unsigned Sz>
struct fun<R(Args...), Sz> {
  using invoker_t = R(*)(void*, Args&&...);
  invoker_t invoker;
  unsigned char buffer[Sz];
  template<class T, class M>
  static details::mem_fun_invoker_t<R(Args...), T, M> mem_fun_invoker(T* t, M m){ return {t, m}; }
  template<class T>
  static details::ptr_invoker_t<R(Args...), T> ptr_invoker(T* t){ return {t}; }
  template<class T, class U, class Ret, class...Ts>
  fun(T* t, Ret(U::*mem)(Ts...)) {
    auto invoke = mem_fun_invoker( t, mem );
    static_assert(sizeof(invoke) <= Sz);
    ::new( (void*)buffer ) decltype(invoke)(invoke);
    invoker = invoke.invoker();
  }
  template<class T, class U, class Ret, class...Ts>
  fun(T const* t, Ret(U::*mem)(Ts...)const) {
    auto invoke = mem_fun_invoker( t, mem );
    static_assert(sizeof(invoke) <= Sz);
    ::new( (void*)buffer ) decltype(invoke)(invoke);
    invoker = invoke.invoker();
  }

  template<class Ret, class...Ts>
  fun(Ret(*f)(Ts...)) {
    auto invoke = ptr_invoker( f );
    static_assert(sizeof(invoke) <= Sz);
    ::new( (void*)buffer ) decltype(invoke)(invoke);
    invoker = invoke.invoker();
  }
  // TODO: SFINAE
  template<class Lambda>
  fun(Lambda&& lambda) {
    auto invoke = ptr_invoker( &lambda );
    static_assert(sizeof(invoke) <= Sz);
    ::new( (void*)buffer ) decltype(invoke)(invoke);
    invoker = invoke.invoker();
  }
  R operator()(Args...args) {
    return invoker(&buffer, static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
  }
  explicit operator bool()const {return invoker;}
};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef72347ec1f5f092).

The above is standards compliant and does not rely upon `std`.  Writing the SFINAE to ensure the `Lambda&&` overload isn't called in bad situation may require rewriting some of `std`, like `std::is_same` and `enable_if`.